# C#: How to stop a method with a timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I'm trying to set a timer for a database connection. Basically, if after X seconds the connection doesn't respond, I want the connection method to stop, and return a warning using Winforms in C# .NET.

Comment: What have you tried already?  What _specifically_ is not working?

Comment: Please show the code you use to talk to the db. A blocking `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` will not "return" just because your timer elapsed. In most db apis you can set timeout values to achieve what you want. But how _you_ should do it I can't tell without seeing your code.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The connection.ConnectionTimeout property is what you actually need.

> Gets the time to wait while trying to establish a connection before
>   terminating the attempt and generating an error.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you sure by "connection responds" OP mean the moment they _open_ the connection or also the answers to queries? In this case they will also need the command timeout. But they didn't even tell if we're taling about a `SqlConnection`.